# Trigger Multiple Instances of a Number Counter Individually during page scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've gotten the JavaScript to work for this on my website, but now need for it to be triggered individually when each statistic is revealed during scroll. Currently, all numbers count up at the same time, but I need the Script to be altered in order to achieve the "Count Up" animation individually for each number that I have on my website. [HERE](https://codepen.io/dmcreis/pen/VLLYPo) is the link to the original codepen and below is the Script that I'm using from that pen.

```
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
$('.counter-value').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {

      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }

    });
});
a = 1;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your duration should be dependent on countTo variable, something like `duration: countTo * 50,` Adjust to get the desired result.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.counter-value').each(function() {
    var contentTop = $(this).offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > contentTop) {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: $this.text()
      }).animate(
        {
          countNum: countTo
        },
        {
          duration: countTo * 50,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you mind elaborating just a bit as I'm not the most JavaScript savvy. How would I write this exactly? Thank you!

Comment: Replace `duration: 2000,` in your code with `duration: countTo * 50,`

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I went ahead and added that, but still seem to be having the same problem where all of the instances are being triggered at once. What does the number 50 represent in your example?

Comment: I have edited the answer with working code. What happens here is when each elements comes into view, the timer will start. duration is in milliseconds, so 50 is just a factor to adjust the duration depending on countTo variable.